# Short exact sequence of chain complex with non-trivial connecting homomorphism

Tags: homological-algebra

Title is pretty straightforward, it is almost a duplicate of [Example of Short exact Sequence of chain complexes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1429279/987127) but I was unable to understand the answers. I have tried many complexes, and unable to find one where the connecting homomorphism. If possible, please provide a simple example which doesn't involve topology. Hopefully something with complexes containing $\mathbb{Z}$ only.

Comment: What is too complicated with paul garrett’s answer to the linked thread? There’s no topology in there are the spaces involved are fairly small.

Comment: While the title is straightforward, your question should be understandable without its title. And it isn't.

Comment: In any case pick any non split exact sequence 0\to A\to B\to C\to 0, resolve the two endpoints A and C projectively, use the horseshoe lemma to obtain a projective resolution of the middle term B. Now you have an exact sequence of complexes. Apply hom(-,A) to everything to obtain a short exact sequence of complexes. Its connecting morphism is not zero.

Answer (score 3):

This one's pretty simple:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0 & \to & 0 & \to & 0 & \to & 0 & \to & 0 \\
  & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
0 & \to & 0 & \to & \mathbb{Z} & \to & \mathbb{Z} & \to & 0 \\
  & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
0 & \to & \mathbb{Z} & \to & \mathbb{Z} & \to & 0 & \to & 0 \\
  & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
0 & \to & 0 & \to & 0 & \to & 0 & \to & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$
where all maps $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ are the identity.

Comment: Indeed, it cannot get simpler than drawing the smallest SES of complexes of free modules that supports the chase in the snake lemma. :)

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ext}{Ext}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}$Let me explain why Mariano's approach works. Suppose indeed that $\xi : 0 \to A \to B \to C\to 0$ is a non-split short exact sequence of modules over some ring $R$, meaning it does not represent the zero class in $\Ext^1(C,A)$.

Consider resolutions $P'\to A$ and $P''\to C$, and then build a resolution $P$ of $B$ of the form $P'\oplus P''$ (but a priori a differential that adds a morphism at the top right, as in the *Horshoe Lemma*).

If you apply $\hom(-,A)$ to $P'\to P\to P''$ and take homology, what you get is the long exact sequence

$$\hom(C,A) \to \hom(B,A) \to \hom(A,A) \to \Ext^1(C,A) \to \cdots$$

One can show that the image of the identity $A\to A$ in $\hom(A,A)$ is sent to the class of $\xi$ in $\Ext^1(C,A)$, which is non-zero, so the connecting morphim $\hom(A,A) \longrightarrow \Ext^1(C,A)$, which is given by right multiplication by $[\xi]$, is not zero.

For a concrete example, let $A = C = \mathbb Z/2$ and $B = \mathbb Z/4$ over $R = \mathbb Z$. Then any short exact sequence with these modules is not split, and the connecting morphism is not zero.

*Add*. If you follow this construction in this case, you will get the following SES of complexes

$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0 & \to & \Z & \to & \Z^2 & \to & \Z & \to & 0 \\
  & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
0 & \to & \Z & \to & \Z^2 & \to & \Z & \to & 0 
\end{array}
$$

where the horizontal maps are $i_1$ and $\pi_2$, the two vertical maps $\Z\to \Z$ are multiplication by $2$, and the third vertical map
is given by the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

If you do $\hom_\Z(-,\Z/2)$ and follow the definition of the chase in the snake lemma, you will see that the connecting morphism
$$\delta : \hom_{\Z}(\Z/2,\Z/2)\cong \mathbb Z/2 \to \mathbb Z/2 \cong \Ext_\Z^1(\Z/2,\Z/2)$$
is the identity. Indeed, the vertical maps $\Z/2\to \Z/2$ are zero, the map $(\Z/2)^2 \to (\Z/2)^2$ is the nilpotent map
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and this is all you need to conclude.